# Java compilation Error for an enum type "The public type EngineType must be defined in its own file Car.java"

Tags: java, oop, enums, compiler-errors

I am new to java, and this is the second time I write a code in it. I have an error stating that The public type EngineType must be defined in its own file. EngineType is an enum type and I have mentioned it outside the class Car, from my oriented programming point of view, as a former C++ student, everything must be okay. Can you please look at my code and help me? Thank you very much for your willing to help me.

```
       package ro.ase.classes1;

    import ro.ase.interfaces1.mobility;

    public final class Car extends vehicle implements mobility,Cloneable
    {
        public final int maxNbofkm=1_000_000;  
        public Enginetype Enginetype;
        private float speed;

        public Car()
        {
            super();//it s mandatory to be on first line of the constructor
            Enginetype=Enginetype.gas;
            speed=0;
        }

        public Car(String _name,Enginetype _enginetype,float _speed)
        {
            super(_name,true);//call the base constructor
            Enginetype=_enginetype;
            speed=_speed;
        }

        @Override
        public void DisplaySpeed() {
            System.out.println(String.format("The %s car runs with %f km/h", Enginetype.toString(),speed ));
        }

        @Override
        public void Start() {

        }

        @Override
        public void Stop() {

            System.out.println("The"+Enginetype.toString()+"car has stopped");
        }

    }
enum Enginetype{gas, diesel,hybrid,electric}
```

[CODE WITH THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x7En.png)

Comment: Please do not link the image of the code. Post the code here. However, you are getting compilation error as You can have only one public class in a single file in java. But in your case you have made Car and EngineType both public.

Comment: Either make `EngineType` non-`public`, move it to it's own properly-named file, or make it a member of the `Car` class.

Comment: In Java you are not allowed to declare more than one top level class per file (the top level class must have the same name with the java file where is declared). If you want to declare more classes in one file then you must use nested classes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Amit Bera it is not working, I ve tried to make both the class and the enum public , and the error is still there.

Comment: @Corina You must have only **one** of them as public.

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have your Enum class defined public outside of your Car class - **having two public classes in one file is not allowed in Java.** You can therefore fix this in one of three ways:

1. Make the Enum private.
2. Place the public Enum into a separate file.
3. Put the Enum inside the Car class.

For example:

Case 1:

```
public class VowelPrint  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Vowels.A);
    }
}

enum Vowels {
    A, B, C;
}
```

Case 3:

```
public class VowelPrint  {

    public enum Vowels { //Can also be private
        A, B, C;
    }  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Vowels.A);
    }
}
```